# Recoding all variables based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I'm trying to recode all the variables in my dataset that are on an "agree/disagree" scale to numeric values. I've tried using mutate_all and case_when, but then it returns NA values for variables like the id column and var3(data below). Here's the code I was using:

```
newdat <- olddat %>% mutate_all(funs(case_when(. == "Strongly Disagree (1)" ~ 1,
                                               . == "Disagree (2)" ~ 2,
                                               . == "Neutral (3)" ~ 3,
                                               . == "Agree (4)" ~ 4,
                                               . == "Strongly Agree (5)" ~ 5)))
```

What I want to happen is below:

HAVE DATA

```
id     var1                      var2           var3      var4
 1     Strongly Disagree (1)     Agree (4)      5         Agree (4)
 2     Strongly Disagree (1)     Neutral (3)    6         Neutral (3)
 3     Disagree (2)              Neutral (3)    4         Strongly Agree (5)
 4     Strongly Disagree (1)     Agree (4)      9         Disagree (2)
 5     Neutral (3)               Agree (4)      2         Agree (4)
```

WANT DATA

```
id     var1   var2   var3   var4
 1     1      4      5      4
 2     1      3      6      3
 3     2      3      4      5
 4     1      4      9      2
 5     3      4      2      4
```

P.S.
Tried searching for an existing answer to this but I couldn't find one! Maybe I was phrasing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_all` as you want to change only selected columns because by default in `case_when` the values which are not matched are turned to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(var1, var2, var4), 
                     ~(case_when(. == "Strongly Disagree (1)" ~ 1,
                                 . == "Disagree (2)" ~ 2,
                                 . == "Neutral (3)" ~ 3,
                                 . == "Agree (4)" ~ 4,
                                 . == "Strongly Agree (5)" ~ 5)))

#  id var1 var2 var3 var4
#1  1    1    4    5    4
#2  2    1    3    6    3
#3  3    2    3    4    5
#4  4    1    4    9    2
#5  5    3    4    2    4
```

As there are many columns to do this, we can first find out which columns need to change and then use `mutate_at`

```
cols <- which(colSums(sapply(df, grepl, pattern =  "Agree|Disagree")) > 0)

df %>%
    mutate_at(cols, ~case_when(. == "Strongly Disagree (1)" ~ 1,
                    . == "Disagree (2)" ~ 2,
                    . == "Neutral (3)" ~ 3,
                    . == "Agree (4)" ~ 4,
                    . == "Strongly Agree (5)" ~ 5))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I actually have ~100 variables, is there a way to only do this to those that have the agree/disagree scale? More than 50 use this scale.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply extract the numeric code from each cell since you already have it in parenthesis. No need to `recode`. Here's a way using `stringr::str_extract()` -

```
have %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var")), ~as.integer(str_extract(x, "[0-9]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this looks kind of ugly and I am sure there are simpler solutions, but it should work:

```
newdat <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(olddat), function(x){if(x %in% c(1,4)){return(olddat[x])}else{return(sapply(olddat[x], function(y){as.numeric(gsub("[()]","",strsplit(y, split = " ")[[1]][2]))}))}}))
```

What it does is basically go through each column. If it's the 1st or the 4th column it returns the column as it is. If it is any of the others: It splits each cell at the white space with `strsplit()`, then takes the second half, removes the brackets with `gsub()` and converts it into numeric with `as.numeric()`.

**Edit:**

If you have many columns and don't want to specify them manually, you can filter by the column class:

```
newdat <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(olddat), function(x){if(class(x) == "integer"){return(olddat[x])}else{return(sapply(olddat[x], function(y){as.numeric(gsub("[()]","",strsplit(y, split = " ")[[1]][2]))}))}}))
```